# Onclick url not opening in wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, url

Here i made a WordPress Website which working correctly but i got some problems occurs like 
Home page opened good but there no any url is opening on click

Here is my website : http://www.itztotalsolutions.com/

I tried many Plugins like URL cleaner, broken links, also check `.ht-access`
But it seem no any problem because it is with default setting

Also i have to tried a db reset and update from backup.

Link was direcly opend means page is available, and if try direct url it working,
also on open in new tab it opened but just on click from menu it is not opened.

.htaccess is :

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: Can you show your .htaccess?

Comment: Something is wrong with your JS, it loads and then hangs.

Comment: ya it's default worpress htaccess
@AliGajani what is solutions for it ? is any plugins worked for solutions ?

Comment: Why can't I right click on your site to inspect element?

Comment: right click protection use F12 for it

Comment: One of your js file is trying to open `http://samir.local`

Comment: can you define which JS file... i couldn't found it ..

Comment: anubhava can you help me for it ?